# Why is this text red when I check to see if a USB device is connected?

Tags: usb, android

I am trying to get my Galaxy Tab 10.1 to connect to my Ubuntu 11.04 computer. It's not working, and I've asked about it on the [Android SE site](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/21730/5892). However, it seems there might be issues on the Ubuntu side, so I'm asking about that here.

When I run this `ls /dev` command, it gives me a response indicating that the device is detected:

```
$ ls /dev | grep gtab
gtab
```

But the text is red, which makes me think something is wrong. It looks like this:

[image: red_text_gtab]

Is this red text indicitive of a problem, and is it fixable?

Comment: I'd recommend opening another question that helps you solve your problem with your Galaxy Tab 10.1. Don't worry about the red text, in this case it is a good thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the standard options that grep gets when it is executed as follows:

```
$ set | grep -i grep
GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto '
```

Grep simply colors the seach term, so you can easily find it on your screen.

The problem you are referring to is entirely unrelated to the colorized output of grep.  Grep simply prints out lines from a file (or standard input) that match a certain search term (gtab). It does not indicate any error, it just helps you find text.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but I don't understand what to do with the output of `set | grep -i grep`. It fills my screen with tons of unformatted code.

Comment: To get an idea what grep does, try if you can spot the difference between the following two commands: 1) `ls /dev` and 2) `ls /dev | grep gtab`